# React-native-popup-dialog is not closing after page changes

Tags: react-native, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm using this package for dialog.Some pages i got opens this dialog automaticly when user comes in.Problem is when user clicks another screen ot button(while dialog is opening) . app navigates to another screen and dialog still opens.

```
import Dialog, {
  DialogFooter,
  DialogButton,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
} from 'react-native-popup-dialog';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    
      controlDialog: false, 
    };
  }
```

in blur i close it but nothing happens

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const t = this;
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      this.setState({controlDialog:false})

    });
```

in render the dialog is

```
<Dialog
  visible={this.state.controlDialog}
  width={0.8}
  footer={
    <DialogFooter style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>
      <DialogButton
        textStyle={{
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: "normal",
          color: "white",
        }}  
        text="Later"
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ controlDialog: false }, () => {});
        }}
      />
      <DialogButton
        textStyle={{
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: "normal",
          color: "white",
        }}  
        text="OK"
        onPress={() => {}}
      />
    </DialogFooter>
  }
>
  <DialogContent></DialogContent>
</Dialog>;
```

What tryed

```
componentDidUnmount() {
    this.setState({controlDialog: false});
    alert('1');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({controlDialog: false});

    alert('2');
  }
```

tabbar

```
function TabBar({state, descriptors, navigation}) {
  return (
    <Box
      pb={Platform.OS=='android'?10:25}
      bg="white"
      flexDirection="row"
      style={{
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 20,
      }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];

        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            NavigationService.reset(route.name);
          }
        };

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dialog `componentDidUnmount()` method of the class lifecycle. This method gets called when you leave the screen.

```
  componentDidUnmount() {
  
     this.setState({controlDialog:false})    

   }
```

Comment: I tryed  once componentWillUnmount and that wasnt worth

Comment: Are you using bottom tab bars to navigate?

Comment: Not a default tabbar. I got js file named as Tabbar.I added to question